# Installing Team Foundation Server (Migrate from StarTeam)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, starteam, tfs-migration

We are currently using StarTeam as our source control, but I am looking into alternatives. We are licensed for Team Foundation Server so I am thinking of using that as I believe it can integrate with VB6 and VS2010 Prof? (StarTeam doesn't integrate with either - at least the version we have doesn't)

Looking briefly at the features of TFS it seems there is a lot in there. To start with I just want SourceCode control.  Does anyone know of a good step by step idiot's guide to setting this up? What needs to be installed where, what needs to be backed up etc, etc?

Also do I need to install anything else on my client to get VS2010 to work with it?

I don't really care about migrating the data from StarTeam but if anyone knows how this can be done I would be interested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Visual Studio clients, you'll have to install Team Explorer - there's an installer on the TFS media, or you can [download it separately](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38). Each Visual Studio has to have a matching Team Explorer version installed (so if you have VS2008, you'll have to install Team Explorer for 2008), but to access later TFS servers, you generally have to install an extra update. For VB 6 (or VS2003), you'll have to use the [TFS MSSCCI provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6).

As to installing the server, all I'd recommend is install it somewhere first and play around with it before you install it for production use - get some familiarity with it. The install process is relatively straightforward.